# Get Chord Name From a Given Set of Notes

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that gets the proper chord name given certain Notes, user may or may not inform which from the notes is the root.

I suppose that the process in recognizing a chord name differs for how many notes are given, so maybe there should be an algorithm for triads, one for 4 note chords, and another for 5+ notes? Or is there a general way of approaching this? maybe chord patterns?

Comment: You could transform every pitch class set to its prime form, and then use that as a key for a chord dictionary. This answer contains information about how to find the prime form: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82120/is-there-a-way-to-determine-a-sets-prime-form-when-given-its-interval-vector/82173#82173 Also check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory_(music)

Comment: What in your opinion is a proper chord name? Even _the_ proper chord name...? Can you give an example of an improper chord name?

Comment: @YourUncleBob this is pretty interesting, I did not knew about Set Theory, I think I'll get a book.

Comment: Actually, the prime form of a pitch-class set in set theory is found through rotation and mirroring, which means e.g. that a major and minor triad both have prime form (0,3,7). For your use case, you should use only rotation, not mirroring, so that you get (0,4,7) for major triads.

Comment: You haven't said what your input or output data will be.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis The input will be a set of notes, the output should be a Chord name, kind of Logic's pro midi monitor.

Comment: @YourUncleBob so its like representing chords in semitones from the root?

Comment: @ChecheRomo, I meant actual examples like input `D♭4` versus `d♭′′` and output `D♭` versus `N6`, and as ttw pointed out augmented sixth chords are tricky, how would you name a German augmented sixth, just `Gr+` or `Ab#6`, or decide it's a tritone sub and call it `Ab7`? You have to output to a particular naming system, in part that will determine your algorithm.

Comment: @ChecheRomo Well, sort of. The root will not necessarily be at the bottom. But the same collection of notes will always give the same prime form, whichever inversion you use. So it's a way of reducing the huge number of possibilities to a smaller dictionary. Every prime form may still be open to interpretation; C-F-G-Bb is (0,2,5,7) starting on F, but that could still be Csus4b7, or fourths stack on G, or Fsus24, or Bb13... But those options would be the same for every (0,2,5,7) chord.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some chords (at least in Common Practice Period harmony) cannot be named out of context. Some trivial examples: F-Ab-Db-F is a Db major chord in and of itself but if resolved to G, it may be a Neapolitan Sixth.

The collection: Ab-C-Eb-F# is a German Sixth if resolved to G-C-E-G thence to G-B-D-G(or F). It's a dominant seventh if resolved to Db-F-Ab or perhaps a tritone substitution. Possibly using F# for the German Sixth and Gb for the dominant seventh helps however composers do approach the chord as a German Sixth and resolve it as dominant seventh and vice versa.

Some ambiguities are matters of taste. In San Antonio Rose (the only song I can think of quickly that does this) the opening chords are Bb-Eb-C7-F7; when I play this piece or other similar pieces I think I-IV-II7-V7 (especially as vocalists may want me to transpose) but while laying out a chord scheme during composing, I think I-IV-V7/V-V7 which shows the structure and would explain a Bb-Eb-C7-d-g-c6-F7-Bb as a secondary dominant resolving on a deceptive cadence followed by a cycle of fifths.

One thing you could do (to get back to the original question) is to rearrange the note collection to have as many thirds as possible and name the chord from there. Moving the notes around should indicate which inversion one has. D-F-G-B can be arranged to be G-B-D-F with a maor third followed by by three minor thirds.

Comment: Maximizing the number of thirds makes sense to me, thanks I'll try it this way.

Comment: `N6` versus `Db` is analysis (identifying function in a key) versus naming (identifying root and chord quality.)