# How to derive triads from more complex chords

Tags: guitar, chords

I recently came into possession of a chord diagram book for guitar.

[image: Em11 page]

It explains 7/9/11/13 chords, sus, add, and everything in between, seemingly, for all 12 notes.

What I don't see explained in this book, however, are the notations for triads.

Is there an easy way to extrapolate basic triads from assorted voicings of more complex chords?

Comment: I feel like there might be some lingering confusion behind the question. *Why* do you want to "figure out triads"? Do you mean, "given a photo and tablature of a C chord, how do I learn which note names make up a C chord"? Or do you mean "given a pictured chord, how do I figure out the abstracted root position" or something like that? Maybe edit to explain more about the end goal.

Comment: I've used triads in learning parts of songs I like.  I'd like to learn more about triads and be able to use them in place of full chords.

Comment: Ah, how to simplify complex chords down to triads. And I guess you mean you'd also like to translate it into practicality and know how to then play it on guitar? Like, how to look at this page of Em11 options and instead get some options for just plain Em? Well, the easiest way would be to just turn to the Em page! If you didn't have that, it would take knowing what note each fret was giving you and then leaving out any pitches that aren't part of Em (E, G, or B). A lot of thinking! Maybe easier just to learn all the simple triads from scratch than to figure out "in reverse" like this.

Comment: Can't understand why you'd be looking at complex chords to find simple triads. Explain, please.

Comment: It sounds like there is no way to strip some of these chords to get triads, then.  Correct?

Comment: I still can't figure out why they need stripping. If you want simple triads, play a 'country' open G. The first three strings form a major triad. Transpose at will.

Comment: Yes, you *can* remove extra notes from a chord. But let's put it this way: if the goal is "I want to know how to play an Em chord," then this is the worst place to start. If the goal is "I want to know which simple triad to substitute for an Em11," that's easy: take away the number. It's just Em.

Comment: Em or Em11 had nothing to do with this discussion,  It was a page sampled at random.

Comment: If triad chords are not included, it sounds like the book is intended for someone who already knows them and doesn't need any explanation. Might be worth checking if it isn't the second volume of a series.

Comment: By ‘triad’, do you mean exactly three notes, in close position?  Or do you mean any simple major or minor chord (without suspensions or tensions or anything else added)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out which notes in a guitar fingering of a complex multi-note chord ("chord" = stack of thirds) belong to the chord's basic triad (the first two thirds starting from the chord's root), IF you already know a name for the chord:

- 1. List the notes in the chord's theoretical form (without caring about guitar or figering patterns). For example, a theoretical E11 has the notes E, G#, B, D, F#, A
- 2. Find the note names for all notes in the fingering pattern.
- 3. Take the first three notes in the theoretical chord, for example E, G#, B.
- 4. Mark these notes in the fingering pattern. The rest of the notes are not a part of the basic triad. If you were able to locate at least one instance of every note belonging to the basic triad, then you found a basic triad in the guitar chord.

But chances are that there is no basic triad to be found, because some  practical chord fingerings may not have some notes of the basic triad at all. An example of a fingering or "E11" would be: x77777. In that chord, the fretted notes are, from lowest to highest, E, A, D, F#, B. So the third, G#, is not in the guitar chord at all, and the basic triad E-G#-B cannot be found anywhere. This is because a theoretical 11 chord doesn't usually work because of the clash between the 3rd and the 11th. But the chord you get by omitting the 3rd is useful, and it has become common in practice to use the name "11" for it.

Another, perhaps more commonly deliberately omitted note is a (perfect) fifth, which does not have as much harmonic impact as other chord tones. A good example might be x5465x for Dmaj9. The guitar chord has the notes D, F#, C#, E, and the fifth, A, is missing.

However, if we look at the example chord E11, it contains a triad, actually even two of them in the guitar fingering: A-D-F# and D-F#-B, which are a second inversion of D major and first inversion of B minor, respectively. A good guitarist might play one of those triads when they see an E11 chord symbol. It is a good habit of guitarists to play fewer notes, and leave out bass notes, if there are many players in the band, particularly a bass player and keyboards or horns. Playing fewer notes leaves more space for others and makes the music more open and less muddy.

Some keywords for finding information about such alternative ways to play chords: (1) rootless chords, (2) shell voicings, (3) upper structure triads.

Comment: Thank you.  This is the help I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you know one or both of these things. Notes on strings/frets of the guitar, and/or notes which make up the chord shown. Slight problem: Em11 isn't a triad. It has the basic triad (usually), but on guitar, anything after '7th' should contain other notes, notably 7, 9 and 11. The full note list for Em11 would be E, G, B, D, F♯ and A, but on guitar, it's often impossible to play all 6 notes simultaneously. So the important notes may take precedence. Those being E (root), 3rd (G), 7th (D) and 11th (A). Each shape may/may not contain all the notes quoted, although without those in the last sentence, it won't be Em11.

Comment: Thanks.  If I have three notes on three separate strings, how do I know which note the triad is named for?  I assume that depends on the circle of 5ths.  If I have G on the 6th string, C on the 5th, and E on the 4th string, is this a C triad because it is the root?

Comment: @JasonPSallinger Well, working from the book pictured, you know it's a C chord because it's on the C chord page! But, throwing away the book: given three pitches—in any octave, on any strings—you figure out which triadic chord it is by imagining it in [root position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_position). You could work it out on staff paper, trying to get the notes into that "snowman shape." Once you get it, the bottom note is the name (root) of the chord. BUT all this comes with one big warning:

Comment: This triad is not in the book I referenced in the image.

Comment: See [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/132314/78419) and my answer to it: when you find a chord in a "real song," you can't always know what chord it is just from the notes. The context helps us decide what these notes are doing and therefore what counts as the name of the chord.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that this particular book only covers extended chords?   I guess that's possible.  Or are there shapes for a basic Em triad on an earlier page?

Or are you asking how extended chords can be broken up into a number of simple triads?   Let's look at the Em11 chord on the page you showed us.  Yes, that extended chord contains Em, G, Bm and D triads.   If you see the chord symbol 'Em11' you could play any of those triads and not sound wrong.   You'll find this concept much easier to work with using notation than in trying to modify chord shapes though..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way because complex chords grow out of simple chords, not the other way around. What you need to do is understand the 5 basic chord shapes, C,A,G,E,D and their minor counterparts where applicable (I won’t address diminished or augmented triads in this answer). Those five chords are part of the CAGED system. You also should know the notes on the fingerboard to the 12th fret of the E,A and D strings.

The basic premise is by using either a barre or a capo you can play any of the five chords anywhere on the neck by using these shapes. The diagram below shows the five shapes and how you can use them all to play a C chord.

C shape: red

A shape: purple

G shape: green

E shape: yellow

D shape: light blue

The numbers in the circles are the chord tones. This is the same basic concept as the page you posted, where there are Em11 chords spread across the entire fingerboard. You can see how if you play for example, an A shape or chord on the 3rd fret or a E shape on the 8th fret you end up with a C chord. This information allows you to play any major chord anywhere on the neck using the 5 basic shapes. It also works for the minor counterparts of the 5 shapes, although G and C shapes don’t have as practical a minor version as the other three.

Here is a link to the page I got this diagram from but there are a multitude of sites with this information: https://www.fingerstyleguitar.rocks/advanced-chords/caged-major/

There are other ways to play triads besides these five but this system gives you a great foundation to work with.

[image]